# Finding unused methods in IntelliJ (excluding tests)

Tags: intellij-idea, static-analysis

I ran into a method today that is .. not used anywhere .. but is tested. Since it is used by a test, `IntelliJ` did not flag the method as 'unused'.

Does `IntelliJ` allow for the following search condition "Find methods that are unused with the exception of tests, where test is defined as anything with `@Test` annotation"

Comment: This is really annoying. I don't want my declerations to be only used in tests. I want to be warned about them if they are only used in tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a related feature request:

- [IDEA-56519](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56519) Inspection for unused code needs options to take into account methods run by test harnesses

While the first point is already covered by the **Configure annotations...** option in the inspection settings, the second point is still valid:

> An option such that a test method (as described above) is not considered an entry point. This is so that we can eliminate ‘production’ methods that are only used by test methods.

Answer (score 8):

> This feature works only for batch inspection and disabled in the editor.¹

According to the JetBrains [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 EAP Makes Unused Code Detection More Flexible](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/09/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-makes-unused-code-detection-more-flexible/) blog, it's now possible.

You can find this in Settings > Editor > Inspections > Java > Declaration redundancy > Unused declaration > on the right.

[image: Configuration option to exclude test entry points]

---

¹ Anna Kozlova, comment in said blog post, January 11, 2017