# Finding unused methods in scala using Intelli J

Tags: scala, intellij-15

I am working on a scala project in IntelliJ and want to clean up my code. 
For this, I am looking for a way in which I can get a list of unused methods within my project.

This link didn't answer my question. It is for Java and not for Scala.
[Finding unused methods in IntelliJ (excluding tests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827056/finding-unused-methods-in-intellij-excluding-tests)

Analyze -> Inspect Code for Scala in IntelliJ has an option to select unused symbol but I am unable to drill it down to only check methods.

Comment: As far as I know you can't get it any more specific. But anyways, unused `val`s and `var`s are at least as important as unused `def`s.

Comment: thanks bash0r. Yeah but I was thinking if there was any IntelliJ plugin to get this capability.

Comment: Sorry, nothing I'm aware of.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Analyze -> Inspect code
Under Inspection Profile click on "..." and make sure "Unused declaration" is checked. Chose Whole project option and then OK.

Comment: Cannot find Unused Declaration under Scala language when I click on "...". When I filter, I can see only "Unused Symbol" under Scala.

Comment: Try to search "unused declaration" in the search bar in the window that opened after you clicked on "..."

Comment: I am still to find that option for Scala... for Java I can see it but haven't come across anything so far.

Comment: It doesn't seem to include the play framework references that occur in the generated code from the routes file.  It ended up removing those functions...